# Selenium Chrome Driver hangs on "getCurrentUrl()" of an XML page. When I manually refresh the hanging page, the code finishes executing

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Running on Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-Bit OS, with Chrome Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) and ChromeDriver version 2.37.

The same code runs flawlessly in Firefox. I am using webdriver to fill out a page (say page 1) that will generate an XML link. When I click the link from page 1 it will open the XML page in a new window. My code switches to the window and calls "getCurrentUrl()". Once it hits this snippet of code, it hangs for several minutes and returns:

> [1523382059.135][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer:
>   300.000 [1523382059.138][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.002.

However, if I manually refresh the page, it will return the URL and finish executing.I have tried telling selenium to send control + F5, as well as the refresh methods and even telling it to `get(getCurrentUrl() )`.

Could this be an issue with proxys or maybe an issue with pulling the page, since it is just raw XML?

Thanks for the time and help.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had issues with Selenium and the chrome driver myself. Even though its not ideal have you tried using a implicit or explicit wait? Thread.sleep() has worked for me in the past when all else failed.

Comment: Good advice. I tried it out today to no avail. Its funny that firefox and IE will run flawlessly and chrome will just sit on the new page. I have even tried downgrading both the driver and chrome browser!

Comment: Yea, i ended up ditching the chrome driver and had to use edge.